# sh не видит Java Virtual Machine на Debian 10

Tags: java, linux, debian, jvm

Возникла необходимость поставить себе на Debian 10 одну программу, но во время установки столкнулся вот с этим

```
$ sh Cytoscape_3_7_2_unix.sh
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8.0_152 and at most 9.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
```

при проверке, показывает, что у меня есть только один путь

```
$ update-alternatives --config java 
Есть только одна альтернатива в группе ссылок java (предоставляющая /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

этот путь, собственно и пытался вписать в /etc/environment,

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

но по-прежнему ничего не получается, требует всё то же.

из того, что делал помимо этого:
1) Пытался поставить различные вариации JVM с помощью менеджера пакетов Synaptic
2) скачал с сайта ORACLE Java SE Runtime Environment 8
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и ожидалось, потратил весь день, а успехом попытки не увенчались. Что можно сделать, почему sh не видит JAVA ?
Заранее спасибо и прошу прошения, если назвал что-то не своим именем.

Comment: Пути исправьте. Они не такими должны быть

Comment: @dmtr мне такие пути выдал update-alternatives --config java. не верно ?

Comment: То, что выдает `update-alternatives --config java` и путь в `JAVA_HOME` - это разные вещи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите JRE 8 версии, это решит вашу проблему.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Если после установки скрипт не стартанет с той же ошибкой, тогда явно укажете путь до каталога:

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/каталог-java-8"
```

И выполните команду `source /etc/environment`